# Using Zend_Db_Select to include several tables in one join

Tags: mysql, left-join, zend-db-select

I know usage of Zend_Db_Select is optional, but I was wondering if there was a way to use it to generate the following SQL:

```
         LEFT JOIN (pages p
             , core_url_rewrite url)
            ON p.page_id = mi.page_id
           AND url.page_id = p.page_id
```

.. or if that's not supported. From what i can see you can only join one table at a time. If u include the tables as a Zend_Db_Expr:

```
->joinLeft(new Zend_Db_Expr('(pages p, core_url_rewrite url)'), 
    'ON p.page_id = mi.page_id
    AND url.page_id = p.page_id')
```

then i'd end up with something like the following, which isn't valid

```
         LEFT JOIN (pages p
             , core_url_rewrite url) AS t
            ON p.page_id = mi.page_id
           AND url.page_id = p.page_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple tables JOINs are not supported. 
`Zend_Db_Select` is programmed to support only one array element as the join table parameter name, and in case it is a `Zend_Db_Expr` or `Zend_Db_Select` instance it will assign it the alias 't', assuming that you are entering a single table name / expression.

You can just split it into two `joinLeft`'s, which might be better for future maintaining, and has no difference from what you wanted.